# NullPointerException Google MapView in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mapview

I am using Google MapActivity. I meeting lots of exception like this.
only in android 4.0.3
Is this a bug of android 4.0.3?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.restoreMapReferences(MapView.java:402)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.setup(MapView.java:327)
at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.setupMapView(MapActivity.java:404)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:289)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
at com.dianping.widget.CustomLocationGoogleMapView.<init>(CustomLocationGoogleMapView.java:25)
... 29 more
```

Comment: Are you using Google's appropriate API for that SDK (API 15) ?

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7644635/779408